# PDO - how to use table and column in index of results?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables that both have 'name' as a column. I think my search is successful, but how do I differentiate between the two when as indexes in an array?

SQL Query:

```
$result = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `profs` 
                        INNER JOIN `universities` 
                        ON `profs`.`school_id` = `universities` . `id` 
                        AND `profs` . $searchtype LIKE :query');
$result->bindValue(':query', "%" . $_GET['query'] . "%");
$result->execute();
```

I notice that I can use the period to specify which table (like profs . school_id or universities . id)

I tried something similar to display the results in a table:

```
foreach ($result as $record) {
    echo "<tr><td>", '<a href="individual_sample.php?id=', $record['id'], '">', $record['name'], '</a></td>';
    echo "<td>", $record['universities.name'], "</td>";
    echo "<td>", $record['subject'], "</td>";
    echo "<td>", $record['latitude'], ",", $record['longitude'], " </td>";
    echo "<td>", $record['avg_rating'], "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo    '</table>
```

I tried $record['universities.name'] but I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'profs.school' in 'on clause'Your search did not return any results

Comment: Alias them in your query.

Comment: Shouldn't `universities.name` be just `name` ?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, never use SELECT * syntax for production code, just specify the columns you need and give them each an alias if required. The tables could change in the future, and you never know what someone might add.

Comment: @Maximus2012 my profs table also has a `name` column, so I think it might cause confusion for PHP

Comment: Then using aliases is the way to do it. Using `select *` is not always a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT profs.*, universities.name as university_name FROM `profs` 
INNER JOIN `universities` ON `profs`.`school_id` = `universities` . `id` 
AND `profs` . $searchtype LIKE :query
```

and then access it like

```
$record['university_name']
```

although

```
$searchtype
```

should not be "schools", because it is not a field in 'profs'

Comment: I copy and pasted your search directly and the syntax isn't being accepted. Here's what I currently have, how can alias it?

>"SELECT *, `universities` . `name` AS `schoolname`, FROM `profs` INNER JOIN `universities` ON `profs`.`school_id` = `universities` . `id` AND `universities` . `name` LIKE :query"

re: $searchtype you're right, it's just some left over code from when it had a slightly different function and I didn't correct it properly.

Comment: Never mind! Your way works, I think it was just the $searchtype issue. My current query is:

'SELECT profs.*, `universities`.`name` as schoolname FROM `profs` 
INNER JOIN `universities` ON `profs`.`school_id` = `universities` . `id` 
AND `universities` . `name` LIKE :query'